# Error when Create and Join Group in Asmack

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire, asmack

Here is my code :

```
try
{
 multiUserChat.join(nickname);

 Form form = multiUserChat.getConfigurationForm();
    Form submitForm = form.createAnswerForm();
    for (Iterator<FormField> fields = submitForm.getFields(); fields
            .hasNext();) {
        FormField field = (FormField) fields.next();
        if (!FormField.TYPE_HIDDEN.equals(field.getType())
                && field.getVariable() != null) {
            submitForm.setDefaultAnswer(field.getVariable());
        }
    }
    submitForm.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_publicroom", false);
    submitForm.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_persistentroom", true);

    multiUserChat.sendConfigurationForm(submitForm);
 }

 //Catch
 catch()
```

I got an error when form = multiUserChat.getConfigurationForm(); 
the form is null, so the error was "NullpointerException"

also I got "this room is locked from entry until configuration is confirmed"

Is there anything wrong with my code?

Note : I'm using Openfire server

Thank you for your help.